# Why can I not construct an object of this user-defined type with this constructor argument?

Tags: c++

I am having trouble creating a object of the following type:

```
struct wordType 
{
   string word  = "";
   int    count = 0;
};

wordType object("hello world");
```

The error I get is:

```
[Error] no matching function for call to 'wordType::wordType(std::string&)
```

Comment: And what is the trouble you are facing?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Did you think of the destination of `str`? You passed it as a parameter with `wordType()`, but you did not receive and set it.

Comment: Where is the constructor for `wordType` that takes one (string) argument? This has nothing to do with vectors, which you'd have discovered had you constructed a [MCVE] and reduced the problem to its most simple. I will fix your question for you to demonstrate the point.

Comment: Your `wordType` has no constructor  that just takes a single `string` argument. So why do you expect to be able to construct it like that?

Comment: [Error] no matching function for call to 'myVector::wordType(std::string&)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are trying to construct a `wordType` object using a constructor that `wordType` does not have.  You can add that constructor to your code:

```
struct wordType 
{
  string word = "";
  int count = 0;

  wordType() = default; 
  wordType(const wordType&) = default; 

  wordType(const string &aword) : word(aword) {}  // <-- here
};

wordType object("hello world");
```

Or, you can a local variable without any constructor parameters, and then populate it afterwards:

```
struct wordType 
{
  string word = "";
  int count = 0;
};

wordType object;
object.word = "hello world";
```

Comment: Or you could use `push_back({str, 0});` using aggregate initialization. One might also argue for the use of `emplace_back` in this case..

Comment: `wordType object { "hello world" };` would work without adding a constructor.

Answer (score 7):

Another alternative is to use the brace initializer:

```
struct wordType 
{
   string word  = "";
   int    count = 0;
};

wordType object{"hello world"};
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/EcX00P)

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that was possible like that. Is this example working because of the default initialization in the struct?

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot: See [Aggregate Initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) and [List Initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization).

Comment: It also works without explicitly specifying the struct name.  Updated the answer with the relevant code.

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I've replaced your vector example with a code as similar to OP's as possible. I think this shows the brace initializer more clearly.

Comment: The OP changed the code that was there earlier in the original post.  Don't know why.

Answer (score 4):

Writing

```
wordType object("hello world");
```

tells the compiler you wish to construct an instance of `wordType` called `object` *constructed* with the parameter "hello", but your class doesn't define the matching constructor.

Your options are to use uniform initialization to memberwise initialize the struct:

```
wordType object { "hello world" };
```

Live demo: http://ideone.com/tDJ1kj

or to add a matching constructor:

```
#include <string>

struct wordType {
    std::string word_ = "";
    int count_ = 0;

    // ... other ctors
    wordType(const std::string& word) : word_(word) {}
};

int main() {
    wordType object("hello world");
}
```

Live demo: http://ideone.com/KVt238

N.B

I'd encourage you to use uppercase prefixes for your types (WordType), and to use a distinguishing mechanism for member variables: I used a `_` suffix, so that I can tell `word_` is a member of a type while `word` is a variable/parameter.